# Problem replacing Fragment within another one. (fragments overlapping)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I try go to `SaveRouteFragment` from `RecordRouteFragment`. The result is that both fragments are overlapping on each other.
I was searching Internet and didn't find an anwer to my issue, although some people had similar issues with overlapping.

[image: Overlapping fragments]

fragment_record_route.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".features.routerecording.ui.RecordRouteFragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cl_frg_container">

        // content

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_save_route.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        // content

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

onClickListener from RecordRouteFragment.kt

```
private val btStopRecordOnClick = View.OnClickListener()  {
        stopLocationService()
        viewModel.markRouteAsNotCurrent()

        childFragmentManager.commit {
            replace<SaveRouteFragment>(binding.clFrgContainer.id) //when I replace that with usual R.id.cl_frg_container - nothing changes
            setReorderingAllowed(true)
            addToBackStack("Save a route") // name can be null
        }
    }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: looks like you have to use `fragmentManager` instead of `childFragmentManager`

Comment: @AndreiTanana it doesn't work. Docs: Fragments are also capable of hosting one or more child fragments. Inside a fragment, you can get a reference to the FragmentManager that manages the fragment's children through getChildFragmentManager(). If you need to access its host FragmentManager, you can use getParentFragmentManager().
https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager

Comment: of course fragments can have nested fragments. I thought you want to change `SaveRouteFragment` to `SaveRouteFragment`. For me it looks like at the moment you add `SaveRouteFragment` inside of `SaveRouteFragment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change background color of SaveRouteFragment to e.g. white.

Comment: Even if you hide the child fragment from behind with a background color, clicks will pass through the top fragment to the child.